# LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types after Update 1 RC downgraded to CTP

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

The following code stopped working for no apparent reason after I installed `VS2015 Update 1 RC` and later downgraded to `Update 1 CTP` due to numerous bugs in RC.

Getting:

> Unable to cast the type 'EFCastTest.ResourceGroup' to type 'EFCastTest.ISortable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sorted = GetSorted<ResourceGroup>();
    }

    static T[] GetSorted<T>() where T : class, ISortable
    {
        var ctx = new Model1();
        var sorted = ctx.Set<T>().OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToArray(); // <- in this line
        return sorted;
    }
}
public interface ISortable
{
    int? SortOrder { get; }
}
public partial class ResourceGroup : ISortable
{
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a manifestation of an incomplete fix to a bug in the C# compiler (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4471) which introduced a number of regressions. The original bug (introduced in RTM) removed some cast nodes from expression trees and resulted in a break for existing applications based on LINQ to SQL. The incomplete bug fix (included in Update 1 CTP) was too aggressive about adding the cast node and resulted in various breaks in EF. The final fix is included in Update 1 RC and restores the behavior of the C# compiler pre-Roslyn. Unfortunately I am not sure if you can use the compiler included in RC unless you reinstall RC.

Comment: i just reinstalled RC and it still doesn't work.
it was working no problem with CTP before I upgraded to RC. Now it won't work with neither version. not even with vanilla VS2015.

Comment: @Mikeon Could you check what version of the compiler you are using when you see the problem? You can run csc.exe from the command line or look at the version of assemblies in c:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin. If you are using ASP.NET 5.0 you may get a different version of the compiler depending on the Roslyn packages you get.

Comment: FWIW, I have seen that version 1.1.0.51014 seems to generate the same expression trees as previous versions of the compiler.

Comment: Also, FYI, I added an int Id property to ResourceGroup and was able to produce a model with your code snippet and the query executed without errors using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on one of my computers.

Comment: I was forced to reinstall my entire OS due to that problem so can't check which version I had.
From memory:
I had VS2015 U1 CTP, on top of that I had ASP.NET 5 Beta 8. On top of that U1 RC - at this point it stopped.
Reverting back to U1 CTP and to vanilla VS2015 did not help.